# IIS7 Rewrite rule being duplicated across 2 different websites (unwanted)

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

We have a IIS7 on Windows Server 2008.  It is hosting a handful of sites, on a handful of ip addresses.  2 of those sites are actually wildcards on the domain:

```
*.firstdomain.com
*.seconddomain.com
```

However, I am finding that any URL Rewrite rules I add for one of these "websites", is automatically in the URL Rewrite section for the other.  Similarly, if I disable the rule in in one, it disables in the other.

This doesn't happen with the other sites defined on this server, just these two.  I look at the parent (top level, the server as a whole), and the rule is not there.  Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was going on here.  I hadn't mentioned in my question that the base-folder for both of the websites above was the same - the two different domains host the same apps as each other, they just have different white labels.  I didn't realize these re-write rules were saved by writing them to the web.config - instead, I thought they were saved in some other IIS7 config file independent of the site itself.  So, since they are sharing base folders, they were sharing webconfigs, which meant they were sharing rules.